# GPIO sample code for Linux

Tags: c, linux

```
static int
GPIOUnexport(int pin)
{
    char buffer[BUFFER_MAX];
    ssize_t bytes_written;
    int fd;

    fd = open("/sys/class/gpio/unexport", O_WRONLY);
    if (-1 == fd) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open unexport for writing!\n");
        return(-1);
    }

    bytes_written = snprintf(buffer, BUFFER_MAX, "%d", pin);
    write(fd, buffer, bytes_written);
    close(fd);
    return(0);
}
```

I have a few questions relate to above GPIO code

1)why use ssize_t? why not just use int?

2)is /sys/class/gpio/unexport" a system file? if not what is it?

3)snprintf prints somethings to buffer, then is write function redundant? or what write function can do differently?

4) instead of using open, can I use ioctl function instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I have no idea why the code sample uses `ssize_t`; the return type of `snprintf` is `int` so using an `int` would be better (to avoid an implicit cast). `ssize_t` is signed and in most cases it is at least as large as an `int` so there is probably no harm done.
2. Yes, it is a system file on Linux. Writing the number of a GPIO pin to this file will "unexport" the GPIO pin from the generic GPIO driver, effectively making the driver declare that it will not handle the pin any more (allowing other GPIO drivers to use it).
3. You could use `dprintf` to write directly to a file descriptor `fd` and then you would not need a temporary buffer. `dprintf` is somewhat less known that the other `printf` variants so maybe that's why the author of the original code decided to use an intermediate buffer instead and then just call the standard low-level `write` function.
4. What sort of `ioctl` function you mean?